# Ceph's rados gateways are failing silently

Tags: ceph

The ceph monitors don't say they look after radosgw, and sure enough, my customer's site had two s3 gateways go down, causing an engineer to be awakened in the middle of the night when too many nagios probes failed.

What are the community's suggestions in the way of best practices for monitoring, managing and failing over radogw nodes? Something as compatible as possible with what monitor does for the rest of the ceph world (;-))

--dave